# Streaming data into BigInsights with Hive

Tags: biginsights

I have records being put onto MQ queues.  Is there a good way to pull those off and put into a hive table?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try using Flume builtin JMS support
    http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#jms-source